# EclipseLink in OSGI Error No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, rcp

I have an RCP 3.7 application (Equinox OSGI) using Gemini JPA (v1.2.0) and EclipseLink (v2.5.2).  I can't get the right combination of Require-Bundle in Manifest.MF to read the persistence.xml.  Does anyone have the a working MANIFEST.MF they can share?

All the other questions I found referred to older versions of EclipseLink and an Eclipselink.jar that is not in the distribution.  I read the documentation at Gemini JPA but did not find it specified.

Based on other posts I have also

- Added org.eclipse.gemini.jpa to autoStart=true at startLevel = 3
- Added my bundle with persistence.xml to autoStart=true at default
- Added VM argument -DREFRESH_BUNDLES=false

Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml
Bundle-Name: Local
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.vogelware.simple.local
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: com.vogelware.simple.model,
 com.vogelware.simple.service,
 javax.persistence;version="2.1.0",
 org.osgi.service.component;version="1.1.0"
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gemini.jpa;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.antlr;bundle-version="3.2.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="3.3.1",
 org.eclipse.persistence.core;bundle-version="2.5.2",
 org.eclipse.persistence.jpa;bundle-version="2.5.2",
 org.apache.derby;bundle-version="10.8.2"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/PersonEntityService-local.xml
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"> 

    <persistence-unit name="person" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.vogelware.simple.Person</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:D:\dev\projects\EASA-DB\motordb" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their were several issues that needed to be resolved.

1. No DB provider - Add Gemini DBAccess to project
2. Wrong PersistenceProviderResolver loaded - the static inner class was being loaded instead of OSGiProviderResolver.  Solved by #4 below.
3. Cycles in DS and JPA resulting in multiple Exceptions - Added VM argument -DREFRESH_BUNDLES=false
4. Bundles needed to be configured to autoStart="true" startLevel="3"

   - javax.persistence
   - org.apache.derby
   - org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.derby
   - org.eclipse.gemini.dbutil
   - org.eclipse.gemini.jpa
   - org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint (if used)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to correct a few points:

1. There is no `org.eclipse.gemini.dbutil`, there is `org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.util` instead.
2. The latest version of the Eclipse Gemini JPA is 1.2.0.M1, so `org.eclipse.gemini.jpa;bundle-version="1.2.0"` isn't working for me.

This *MANIFEST.MF* works for me:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.openhab.binding.mybinding;singleton:=true
Bundle-Name: org.openhab.binding.mybinding
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation,
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core,
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind,
 javax.persistence,
 javax.servlet.http,
 javax.ws.rs.client,
 javax.ws.rs.core,
 org.eclipse.jetty.io,
 org.eclipse.jetty.server,
 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler,
 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.component,
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api,
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations,
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client,
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common,
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet,
 org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3,
 org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist,
 org.eclipse.smarthome.config.core,
 org.eclipse.smarthome.core.library.types,
 org.eclipse.smarthome.core.thing,
 org.eclipse.smarthome.core.thing.binding,
 org.eclipse.smarthome.core.types,
 org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator,
 org.glassfish.jersey,
 org.glassfish.jersey.client,
 org.glassfish.jersey.jackson,
 org.slf4j,
 org.testng,
 org.testng.annotations,
 com.google.common.collect
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gemini.jpa,
 org.eclipse.persistence.antlr;bundle-version="3.2.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="3.3.1",
 org.eclipse.persistence.core;bundle-version="2.5.2",
 org.eclipse.persistence.jpa;bundle-version="2.5.2",
 org.apache.derby;bundle-version="10.8.2"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/*.xml
```

This my *persistence.xml*:

```
    <persistence-unit name="supervisor-state" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.gadgetkeeper.hub.supervisor.model.ActivationInfo</class>
        <class>com.gadgetkeeper.hub.supervisor.model.SupervisorState</class>
        <class>com.gadgetkeeper.hub.supervisor.model.Version</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:derby:db/supervisordb;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="supervisor"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="supervisor"/>

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                      value="database"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```